# Laravel + Carbon 2 Carbon::parse always uses apps default timezone

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, php-carbon

Just upgrading from Laravel 5 to Laravel 6, and with that Carbon is also upgraded to version 2.

Running in to a weird problem with `Carbon::parse()`. It seems that no matter what I put in as the second argument to parse - the date is always parsed with the apps default timezone (Europe/Stockholm).

```
$bookingDate = Carbon::parse('2020-08-17 15:00:00', 'Europe/London');
$bookingDate->getTimezone()->getName(); // Europe/Stockholm (mismatch)
```

However, using `Carbon::createFromFormat()`, it works as expected:

```
$bookingDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2020-08-17 15:00:00', 'Europe/London');
$bookingDate->getTimezone()->getName(); // Europe/London
```

This is not a problem when testing in, for example, tinker - as there is no default timezone set in that execution.

So why `->getName()` in the first code returns `Europe/Stockholm`?

Comment: I can't reproduce this bug, when I try it in https://try-carbon.herokuapp.com/ or on my local machine, I get "Europe/London".

The Laravel timezone should not interfere when you explicitly call parse.

Is there a setTestNow() is use?

Please provide a reproductible code chunk.

Answer (score -1):

You can parse using this:

```
Carbon::parse($value)->format('d/m/Y');
```

Comment: Where would I state what timezone the incoming date is in? This will just give me a string. I need a Carbon instance in a specific timezone.